# grok parse optional field pattern doesn't work

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I've got a log like this:

```
ERROR_MESSAGE:Invalid Credentials,THROTTLED_OUT_REASON:API_LIMIT_EXCEEDED
```

I'm trying to parse it with grok using grok debugger:

```
ERROR_MESSAGE:%{GREEDYDATA:errorMassage},THROTTLED_OUT_REASON:%{GREEDYDATA:throttledOutReason}
```

It works, but sometimes the log comes without `THROTTLED_OUT_REASON` field.

```
ERROR_MESSAGE:%{GREEDYDATA:errorMassage}
```

In that case I tried below code since `THROTTLED_OUT_REASON` is an optional field.

```
ERROR_MESSAGE:%{GREEDYDATA:errorMassage}(,THROTTLED_OUT_REASON:%{GREEDYDATA:throttledOutReason})?
```

So this should work for both cases. The given output for the log with optional field is:

```
{
  "errorMassage": [
    [
      "Invalid Credentials,THROTTLED_OUT_REASON:API_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"
    ]
  ],
  "throttledOutReason": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ]
}
```

But the expected output for the log with optional field:

```
{
  "errorMassage": [
    [
      "Invalid Credentials"
    ]
  ],
  "throttledOutReason": [
    [
      "API_LIMIT_EXCEEDED"
    ]
  ]
}
```

expected output for the log without optional field:

```
{
  "errorMassage": [
    [
      "Invalid Credentials"
    ]
  ],
  "throttledOutReason": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ]
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution which gives correct output for both type of logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer using [@Skeeve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6237339/skeeve) 's [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56592548/5430055).

Here it is for anyone who would come up with a similar question:

I've used custom pattern in order to avoid excess eating of `GREEDYDATA` (for `errorMessage` field).

```
ERROR_MESSAGE:(?<errorMassage>([^,]*)?)(,THROTTLED_OUT_REASON:%{GREEDYDATA:throttledOutReason})?
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `GREEDYDATA` it "eats" as much as it can get in order to fill `errormessage`.

I do not know GROK enough to tell you what alternative defined patterns there are, but you should be able to use a custom pattern:

```
ERROR_MESSAGE:(?<errorMassage>.*?),THROTTLED_OUT_REASON:%{GREEDYDATA:throttledOutReason}
```

Comment: ^1 , Thanks @Skeeve, I got the answer using your idea.